# How to validate textbox using bootstrap banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am relatively new to javascript and Im trying to create a banner that will display if textbox is empty. But it doesn't show. How can I make an alert using bootstrap banners?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function validateForm() {
      var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value;
      if (uname == ""){
          bootstrap_alert.warning = function(message) {
            $('#alert_placeholder').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><span>'+message+'</span></div>')
        }

$('#clickme').on('click', function() {
            bootstrap_alert.warning('Please enter your name');
});
          return false;
      }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
Name: <input type: "text" name="uname" id="uname" />
<input type = "button" id = "clickme" value="Submit"/>
<div id = "alert_placeholder"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are several things that you should consider while writing JS code:

1. Always include `$(document).ready(function(){});` if you want your Jquery
   code to wait for html body to load. and once it is loaded you want to
   use your JS code.
2. Another thing that you have created a `validateform()` which is never calling from your code and your main code exists within that function.

I've modified your code to work perfectly

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

 $('#clickme').on('click', function() {
              bootstrap_alert('Please enter your name');
    });
      
           bootstrap_alert = function(message) {
          var uname=$("#uname").val();
        if (uname.length==0){
            $('#alert_placeholder').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><span>'+message+'</span></div>')
        }
        else{
        $('#alert_placeholder').html('');
        }
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
Name: <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" />
<input type = "button" id = "clickme" value="Submit"/>
<div id = "alert_placeholder"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Let me know.. if you need any help in this regard.. I would be gald to help you. Thanks

Comment: What if I have multiple textboxes that I want to have an error box for each?

Comment: If you want to display a single error no matter how many inputs are empty, then this is enough.. but if you want to have an error for each text box, then one solution is to created a div dynamically and append it after that particular input box using after() function in jquery.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: I would suggest you to make another question and I'll answer there as it is a bit different question and if you want to get answer her, let me know.. I'll answer when i go home.. right now i'm busy with some other stuff